# Apache Kafka (KStreams) : How to subscribe to multiple topics?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

**I have the following code**

```
//Kafka Config setup
Properties props = ...; //setup

List<String> topicList = Arrays.asList({"A", "B", "C"});

StreamBuilder builder = new StreamBuilder();
KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream(topicList);

source
.map((k,v) -> { //busy code for mapping data})
.transformValues(new MyGenericTransformer());
.to((k,v,r) -> {//busy code for topic routing});

new KafkaStream(builder.build(), properties).start();
```

**My Problem :** When I add more than one topic to subscribe to (ie A,B,C in above) the Kstream code stops receiving records.

**References :** https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsBuilder.html

**Relevant Documentation**

```
public <K,V> KStream<K,V> stream(java.util.Collection<java.lang.String> topics)

"If multiple topics are specified there is no ordering guarantee for records from different topics."
```

**What I'm trying to achieve :** Have one Kstream (ie 'source' from above) consume/process from multiple topics.

Comment: do you see anything in the logs? have you enabled debug log? also, topics need to be co-partitioned. meaning that num of partitions for each topic, key and partitioning algorithm should be the same.

Comment: You code looks correct. I would look into log4j output -- did the application rebalance correctly (ie, tasks assigned etc). Do you monitor the lag for the input topics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the topics share the same key?

> Note that the specified input topics must be partitioned by key. If
>   this is not the case it is the user's responsibility to repartition
>   the data before any key based operation (like aggregation or join) is
>   applied to the returned KStream.

this maybe your blocker.

Another possible issue maybe the consumer group used.

Comment: Thanks for the help